# Como asignar un Update en el siguiente programa

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, visual-basic

Es una función para guardar una imagen de tipo binario en la base de datos, y en el PRIMARY KEY se guarda el nombre de la persona, quisiera actualizar las imágenes/fotos de las personas.

Me genera esta salida:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tbl_repreTrab'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbl_repreTrab'. The duplicate key values is (). The statement has been terminated.
```

El siguiente programa:

```
Private Sub SaveData()
        Dim pIdDuplicate As Boolean = False


        If And txtTrainingWorldKey.Text <> "" And txtTraningDescription.Text <> "" Then

            Try
                'find is the id is duplicate
                strSQL = "select * from tbl_training where id='" & txtTrainingID.Text & "'"
                connectDB()
                sqlCMD = New SqlCommand(strSQL, connDB)
                sqlDR = sqlCMD.ExecuteReader
                With sqlDR
                    While .Read
                        If IsDBNull(.GetValue(0)) = False Then
                            pIdDuplicate = True

                        Else
                            pIdDuplicate = False

                        End If
                    End While
                    .Close()
                End With
                sqlCMD.Dispose()

                CloseDatabase()

                '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                If txtPathRepEmpre.Text.Trim <> "" Then
                    Save_Image(cmbRepreEmpre.Text, txtPathRepEmpre.Text.Trim)
                End If
                If txtPathRepTrab.Text.Trim <> "" Then

                    Save_Image1(cmbRepreTrabajo.Text, txtPathRepTrab.Text.Trim)
                End If
                '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


                clearAll()
                clear_ImageData()
                iniData()
                FillDG()
            Catch EX As Exception
                MsgBox(EX.Message)
            End Try


        Else
            MsgBox("ERROR:Falata codigo de entrenamiento", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Falta dato")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. El código está incompleto. Lo único que se ve es un select y eso no puede generar un error de llave duplicada, por favor [edit] la pregunta y completar el código.